# Постфиксная запись. Что не так с кодом?

Tags: c++, польская-запись

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
stack <int> stack;
string str;
cin >> str;
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
{
    if (isdigit(str[i]))
    {
        stack.push(str[i]);
    }
    else if (str[i] == '+')
    {
        int a, b;
        a = stack.top();
        stack.pop();
        b = stack.top();
        stack.pop();
        stack.push(b + a);
    }
    else if (str[i] == '-')
    {
        int a, b;
        a = stack.top();
        stack.pop();
        b = stack.top();
        stack.pop();
        stack.push(b - a);
    }
    else if (str[i] == '*')
    {
        int a, b;
        a = stack.top();
        stack.pop();
        b = stack.top();
        stack.pop();
        stack.push(b * a);
    }

}
cout << stack.top();
```

}[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проблема в том, что компилятор выдает 56 (см. скрин ниже)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `cin` прерывает ввод, когда встречает в входной строке пробельный символ.
   воспользуйтесь функцией `std::getline`

   `std::string str;`

   `std::getline(cin, str);`
2. Вы добавляете в стек без правильного приведения представления цифры `char` к типу `int`, правильно делать так:

   `#include <stdlib.h>`

   `stack.push( atoi(&(str[i])) );`

В вашем коде в стек попадает ASCII-код числа, а не само число.

Правильный код: http://cpp.sh/2k3eu